# How to call UserControl Method in Parent page ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrol

I have 4 User Controls inside a Page and the page is inside the Master Page. 
When a link clicked inside the User control that fires a javascript Ajax call to a web method which resides in the Page. Then that page call's the method of User control.

### User Control

```
function statusImageClick(Key) {
    //ajax call to update the grid with the updated/inserted data.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Page1.aspx/UpdateFRStatus',
        data: '{key : "' + Key + '"}',
        ....
}

public void UpdateFRStatus(int key)
{
    .....
}
```

### Page1.aspx

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateFRStatus(int key)
{            
    Page1 pageObj = new Page1();
    pageObj.UpdateFRStatusforAjax(key);
}

private void UpdateFRStatusforAjax(int key)
{ 
    ucFR.UpdateFRStatus(key);
}
```

Question 1: **ucFR.UpdateFRSTatus(key)** gives and error that **ucFR** is null.

Question 2: I am not sure what should be the correct approach for this behavior.

I hope have explained my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods are static and do not have access to the page's controls.

Even though you are instantiating a `Page1` object, it does not have a reference to the controls that are in the page that is hosting the user controls and the page method itself.

Think of ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods as web services hosted by a page, but only hosted in the sense that the logic is written in the page itself. It is not directly connected to the page in context so I would recommend using it only to get data and then raising an event in the user control that the page can subscribe to and react to.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please provide example for this issue.

Comment: Well I am not even sure why you are using a page method at all. Could you please explain the use case for what you are trying to do? I assume you are wanting to do something when the user control's button is clicked, right? What is that something?

Comment: I have to update the status of a record which is inside a collection object when user clicks on a link button of a grid row. That has to be done without doing the postback. I have written the logic in a method inside the user control and on the ajax call from the main page i want to call the logic written in user control.

Comment: @Manoj - you are asking two questions, the first of which was why is the `ucFR` control is `null`? I have answered that for you. I suggest that you accept an answer for this and then post your complete code in a new question that exclusively deals with the mechanism of how you should update an item in the collection without creating a post back.